# Divergence in cartesian coordinates conflicts with spherical divergence.

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

Consider the vector
$$
\vec{a}=f(r)\hat{r}+r\hat{\theta}+r\hat{\phi}
$$
Where $\vec{a}$ is a vector in spherical coordinates and $f(r)$ is a function of $r$.
Let's calculate $\nabla\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})$, where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector.
$$
\nabla\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})=\vec{r}\cdot(\nabla\times\vec{a})-\vec{a}\cdot(\nabla\times\vec{r})
$$
$\nabla\times\vec{r}=0$. Thus, by using divergence formula in spherical coordinates, I concluded that
$$
\nabla\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})=r\cot(\theta)
$$
But, the same calculation in cartesian coordinates lead to
$$
\nabla\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{r})=0
$$
Why is this quantity different in these coordinates?

Comment: In your first equation $\vec{a}=f(r)\hat{r}+r\hat{\theta}+r\hat{\phi}$ what is $\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi}$?

Comment: @Somos [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) is an excellent refresher or starting reference if you are seeing this notation for the first time.

Comment: Your product rule formula is incorrect since there should be a minus sign, but it may not have affected your answer since that term with the sign change vanished. It is hard to tell where you went wrong if you don't post your full calculation in both coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, the sign was incorrect. I checked my results with mathematica, they're completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong identity .

$\nabla \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{r}) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(\epsilon_{ijk}a_jr_k)=\epsilon_{ijk}(\partial a_j/\partial x_i)r_k + \epsilon_{ijk} ( \partial r_k/ \partial x_i)a_j= \vec{r}\cdot (\nabla \times \vec{a} )-\vec{a} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{r}) $

$\nabla \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{r}) = \vec{r}\cdot (\nabla \times \vec{a} )-\vec{a} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{r})$

$\vec{a}=f(r)\hat{r} + r \hat{\theta}+r \hat{\phi}$

$\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$

$\vec{a}\times \vec{r}= -r^2\hat{\phi}+r^2\hat{\theta}$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r^2 E_r)+ \frac{1}{r \sin \phi }\frac{\partial E_\theta}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{r \sin \phi}\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}(\sin \phi E\phi)$

Since the $r$ component is $0$ and the other components only have radial dependence, the divergence is $0$.

Further $\nabla (r^2/2)=\vec{r}$ and for any scalar $f$, $\nabla \times \nabla f=0$ in any coordinate system.

It follows that $\nabla \times \vec{r}=0. $

$\nabla \times \vec{E} = \frac{1}{r \sin \phi}(\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi }(A_\theta \sin \phi)-\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial \theta })\hat{r}+ \frac{1}{r}(\frac{1}{\sin \phi} \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(rA_\theta))\hat{\theta}+\frac{1}{r}(\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(rA_\phi)-\frac{A_r}{\partial \phi})\hat{\phi}$

Since the components of $\vec{a}$ are only dependent on $r$, the derivatives for the  r-component of the curl are 0, so the r coordinate of the curl is 0.

$\nabla \times \vec{a}= 0 \hat{r}  -2\hat{\theta}+2\hat{\phi}$

So $\vec{r} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{a}) = 0. $

Combining this we have $\nabla \cdot (\vec{a} \times \vec{r})=0$

Comment: I'm completely sure that you're using the wrong formula for divergence in spherical coordinates. please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: I first learned about these with $\theta$ and $\phi$ switched, which I think makes more sense intuitively. Keeping that in mind, does my equation otherwise hold?

Comment: I guess you omitted the partial derivative of sine function with respect to phi when you were computing the divergence.